# Are RecordSet Objects Deprecated In .Net 4.5?

Tags: .net-4.5, deprecated, recordset

Are `RecordSet` objects deprecated in the .Net 4.5 Framework? If so, is it possible to include them in a .Net 4.5 Framework project by referencing them?

From my reading, I understand them to be deprecated. I also understand that if your "target" framework is higher than that of the desired reference, the reference *cannot* be included in your solution (the IDE, e.g. Visual Studio 2013, will not allow the inclusion).

I am looking for a definitive, simple answer as none seem to be available elsewhere (though there are certainly troves of information on the web about `RecordSet` and `DataSet`). Again, my question is **not** how to use `RecordSet`, but rather whether it is deprecated and - if so - how to include in a .Net 4.5 Framework solution (which I am under the impression is not possible).

If you are able to attach any references, that would be awesome. I am either trying to prove me "wrong" or someone else "wrong".

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315974) is *one* of the references I have found that seems to suggest `RecordSets` aren't really a part of the .Net piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has never been a type named "RecordSet" in the .NET Framework.  That name was taken, a COM type that had its hay days in the 1990s.  Part of DAO and ADO, COM object models that made it easy to access data.  And found its way into plenty of .NET programs, stuck on data providers of the 1990s or injected by code originally written in VB6 or VBA, the most popular programming tools in the 90s.

No, it is alive and well, ADO is not deprecated.  DAO got the axe 13 years ago when Jet was removed from the standard distribution.  Albeit that it seems to be not quite dead, it is still included with every current Windows version.  Microsoft code never dies.  COM interop in .NET 4.5, what you use under the covers to consume the ADODB type library, has not changed at all.

There was an ill-fated attempt to make ADO more compatible with 64-bit code, fixing a bug in the type library.  Released in Windows 7 SP1, it caused wide-spread dismay and misery so was canceled again.  Hopefully you don't have that viral problem.

Otherwise typical of software, it is not like fine wine, it does *not* age gracefully.  Still using Recordset today does not make sense, you'd at least consider uplifting to the System.Data.Oledb namespace.  Which is the managed .NET wrapper around ADO.